# Install MDATP on Rhel8 but it failed

Tags: linux, rhel, package-management

I have a machine with RHEL8 operating system. I have to install Defender Endpoint for Linux, by following the guide: [Deploy Microsoft Defender for Endpoint on Linux manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/linux-install-manually?view=o365-worldwide#uninstallation)

I came to the passage: **yum install mdatp**
but I get this error

```
[root@rhel8]#yum install mdatp
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Kubernetes                                                                                                                                                   0.0  B/s |   0  B     02:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'kubernetes':
  - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'kubernetes': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

I tried to disable the repository of kubernetes on **/etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo**.
Relaunched the command "yum install mdatp" and I get this:

```
[root@rhel8]# yum install mdatp
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

packages-microsoft-com-prod                                                                                                                                  9.7 MB/s | 7.9 MB     00:00
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:15 ago on Thu 14 Oct 2021 10:54:14 AM CEST.
Dependencies resolved.
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Architecture                         Version                                    Repository                                                 Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mdatp                                       x86_64                               101.45.00-1                                packages-microsoft-com-prod                                44 M
Installing dependencies:
 libatomic                                   x86_64                               8.4.1-1.el8                                InstallMedia                                               23 k
 mde-netfilter                               x86_64                               100.69.32-1                                packages-microsoft-com-prod                                36 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  3 Packages

Total download size: 44 M
Installed size: 157 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Error opening file for checksum: /run/media/root/RHEL-8-4-0-BaseOS-x86_64/BaseOS/Packages/libatomic-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
Package "libatomic-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64" from local repository "InstallMedia" has incorrect checksum
Error: Some packages from local repository have incorrect checksum
```

With the command:

```
[root@rhel8]# dnf repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

repo id                                                                                      repo name
InstallMedia                                                                                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4.0
docker-ce-stable                                                                             Docker CE Stable - x86_64
kubernetes                                                                                   Kubernetes
packages-microsoft-com-prod                                                                  packages-microsoft-com-prod
```

If I install the package **libatomic** from this link [libatomic](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/libatomic-8.4.1-1.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) and the package **mdatp** from this link [mdatp](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/microsoft-prod-x86_64/mdatp_101.02.55.x86_64.rpm.html), do I destroy the machine?? 
How can I manage to install the mdtap command?

Thanks and good evening!

Comment: »»not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management«« : No genuine basic repo will be available. You can migrate the OS to the CentOS 8 repo (eol Dec.2021) or e.g.  Rocky Linux 8   https://mirrors.rockylinux.org/mirrormanager/mirrors   ........ or you can buy a Redhat license.

Comment: Hi Knud, I cannot do it because it is a machine prepared by a company :(

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo
```

Comment: Simply replay error says the package is not available in repository this package available in microsoft repo.
Above answer is tested in my scenario

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/673362/edit) to include this information. While you’re at it, could you explain why you’re suggesting the RHEL 7 repository? The target system is running RHEL 8.

Comment: Hi Rizwan, I already did those commands, the command "yum install yum-utils" it gives me the first error I reported regarding kubernetes.
\
Hi Stephen, where do you see the rhel7 repository?

Comment: @Kanuc in a previous version of the answer. Rizwan fixed that, but hasn’t added any explanation to their answer, which is why I haven’t deleted my comment.

Comment: In the end, I enabled the repository /etc/yum.repos.d/Kubernetes.repo (enabled = 0) and I mounted disk to install dependencies    :)

Answer (score 0):

```
yum clean all
rm  -rf /var/cache/yum/*
subscription-manager refresh

sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo

sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/8/prod.repo
sudo rpm --import http://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

yum install mdatp
```

Comment: Please see the guidelines on [writing an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help), then [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739737/edit) your question accordingly. When editing please click the question mark on the top right corner to see how to use the formatting buttons correctly. As a new user you should take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), check at least Asking and Answering -sections in the Help center and review some older questions with accepted answers to learn how the site works.